# sleep using java.time.Duration

Tags: java-8

I work in java8 and would like to use class `java.time.Duration` to set up sleep time.
As I understand Duration is composed via seconds and nanoseconds.
So waiting Duration time is should be equivalent to waiting:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(long);
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(long);
```

Is my understating is correct?

Comment: It doesn’t matter what the `Duration` object is composed of, as long as it supports handy conversion methods for every purpose. So you can use, e.g. a single `LockSupport.parkNanos(duration.toNanos());`

Answer (score 0):

The TimeUnit.sleep functionality only provides millisecond granularity for sleeping. It forwards to Thread.sleep and the nanoseconds are ignored.

```
    public static void sleep(long millis, int nanos)
    throws InterruptedException {
        if (millis < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
        }

        if (nanos < 0 || nanos > 999999) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                "nanosecond timeout value out of range");
        }

        if (nanos >= 500000 || (nanos != 0 && millis == 0)) {
            millis++;
        }

        sleep(millis);
    }
```

If you want something more reliable have a look at LockSupport.parkNanos. You should be able to get something like 50us granularity on your sleep on Linux.

https://hazelcast.com/blog/locksupport-parknanos-under-the-hood-and-the-curious-case-of-parking/

Comment: If you're truly mad or happen to have had a sadistic teacher, you can calculate the time delay directly as a result of the number of instructions,  their cycle count, and your processor clock speed / ipc

Comment: @Rogue and then, a task switch happens, making your thread proceed far later than calculated. Or `parkNanos` returns earlier for no reason, as it is allowed to do, but checking for the actual elapsed time would take more cycles than the difference to the intended waiting time…

Comment: Checking the nanosecond time would be between 15/30ns.

Comment: You can use CPU affinity to control which threads are running on which cores. If you want, you can even isolate the cores from the general usage of the OS.  https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Thread-Affinity

This would prevent/reduce unwanted context switches.

Comment: But then, you still don’t have real control over the execution timing of Java code that is subject to JIT compiling and runtime optimizations. The more effort you spend on raising the precision, the smaller is the actual gain.

Comment: It depends. For most Java developers it will not matter and they can stay in their protective bubble because performance isn't that relevant. 

But eventually Java interacts with the hardware and with the OS. And you can zoom into what happens on the hardwarelevel (the microarchitecture for example) and how the operating system is implemented by checking for example the Linux source/documentation or run with a profiler that can see what is happening inside the OS (or inside the CPU). So this is after the JIT has optimized the code. 

Java can be pushed a lot further than most people think.